# How to capture IE events

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

I use this code in my program...

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.something.com");
```

It opens that url in IE.User enter some details in the page and click on submit button.Browser navigated those details to other page I want to perform some operations while navigating the page...

How to capture browser navigating event...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of launching a separate browser process, you should consider using the Web Browser control. You can navigate to whatever page you want, capture events, and in general, control the entire browsing process.

---

If you're trying to do this from ASP.NET or some other non-interactive context, then the answer is **very different**.

If the form isn't very complicated, then you might just try using WebClient to post to the URL and read the results. Use WebRequest if things are a little more complicated.

If the form really needs to run in a browser (maybe it needs JavaScript), then you have to run it in a browser. You're not going to get access to the events happening in a browser running in a separate process. And you're not going to be able to run the WeBBrowser control inside of ASP.NET. This means you need to do something more sophisticated.

I would recommend that you follow my original suggestion of writing a simple Windows Forms application that hosts the WebBrowser control. That application will be able to capture events and do anything else that's needed for interacting with IE. In order to have that program interact with ASP.NET, I suggest that you have it self-host a WCF service. Your ASP.NET application would use that service to communicate with the Winforms application, which would, in turn, interact with the browser.

You'll have to force the WCF service to handle only a single request at a time, as there will only be a single WebBrowser control. If you need to handle multiple requests at a time, then you will need to create more than one instance of the winforms application.

Comment: TQ, But Webbrowser control is not worked in ASP.Is there any other solution.

Comment: It's very important that you're trying to do this from an ASP.NET page. You **really** need to tell us.